# fullCalendar - render an event within a time slot (from 8pm to midnight)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I am new to Full Calendar plugin. My requirement states that we should be able to add event  only between 8:00 PM to 12:00 midnight (within a time slot). I am trying hard to implement this but nothing seems to be working. Could someone point me to the solution approach.

I downloaded a sample from http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar-asp-net/downloads/detail?name=CalendarSitev1.1.zip&can=2&q= and everything seems to be working fine. The start and end date always take 12:00:00 AM. The values are passed in the query string.

c# code:

```
context.Request.QueryString["start"] in JsonResponse.ashx
```

JavaScript code:

```
events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
```

How to change the querystring value?

Comment: Please, provide your code. Without code is hard to understand where your problem.

Comment: check minTime and maxTime, that will allow you to limit the time interval for adding events... http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/

Comment: Hi joni, I have added the code. Could you please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the minTime and maxTime properties.
You'll be able to set

minTime: '20:00:00',
maxTime: '23:59:59',

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/

Comment: Hi Enrique, that did not work. I have added the code in my question. Please help me.